# Sounding: mixed layer CAPE calculation

Tags: layer, mixed, metpy

Metpy provides a function to calculate surface based CAPE (metpy.calc.surface_based_cape_cin) or starting pressure based CAPE (metpy.calc.cape_cin). See: https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.html#module-metpy.calc

But is there a simple way or already existing specific module to calculate mixed layer CAPE (CAPE resulting from an ascending air parcel whose the start properties - pressure, temperature, dewpoint temperature - are those of a 100 hPa thickness mixed layer above the surface) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/579

Comment: That particular issue refers to shading with a particular mixed parcel, which is not possible. Calculating CAPE/CIN with such a parcel *is* possible, it's just not trivial. See answer below (once I post it :)  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MetPy's `cape_cin` function takes an arbitrary parcel profile, representing the temperature of a air parcel as it rises through the atmosphere. To get a profile that represents a parcel mixed over a depth, MetPy also has a [`mixed_parcel`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.mixed_parcel.html#metpy.calc.mixed_parcel) function that "Determines the properties of an air parcel that is the result of complete mixing of a given atmospheric layer". This mixed parcel can then be passed to MetPy's `parcel_profile` function to calculate the temperature as an arbitrary parcel rises:

```
import mepty.calc as mpcalc

_, t_parcel, td_parcel = mpcalc.mixed_parcel(p, T, Td, depth=100 * units.hPa)
profile = mpcalc.parcel_profile(p, t_parcel, td_parcel)
mpcalc.cape_cin(p, T, Td, profile)
```

By default `mixed_parcel` will mix the parcel and return it to the first (assumed surface/starting) pressure value in `p`.

MetPy should eventually gain the ability to have this work more readily out of the box, but this works today.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I have indeed calculated mixed parcel CAPE/CIN, by passing the output of mixed layer mpcalc.mixed_parcel module to mpcalc.surface_based_cape_cin (replacing the surface T and Td of the original sounding profile respectively by the T_mixed_parcel and Td_mixed_parcel returned by mpcalc.mixed_parcel). So this is very similar to the way suggested by @DopplerShift (the only minor difference is that I do not use mpcalc.parcel_profile step, because mpcalc.surface_based_cape_cin compute it in itself: see https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/_modules/metpy/calc/thermo.html#surface_based_cape_cin).
So: problem solved (in waiting for an eventual future implementation of a specific module by MetPy to do that in a more straightforwardly way).